# Selenium WebDriver Unable to Find Element by Id, Using Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to pull up an element that only gets created after the JavaScript runs, but I keep getting the following error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"post-count"}' ; Stacktrace: Method FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ threw an error in file:///tmp/tmpittNsw/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js
```

I'm trying to pull this element up on cnn.com.  My code:

```
socket.setdefaulttimeout(30)
browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox
browser.get(article_url_txt) # Load page

result = browser.find_element_by_id("post-count")
```

Comment: Maybe your not giving it time to finish loading, is there no `onready` event you can have call your `find element`?

Answer (score 1):

The element you are looking for is inside an `iframe`.

The following did the trick for me:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

# ...

frame = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_id("dsq1"))
browser.switch_to_frame(frame)
result = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until( lambda x: x.find_element_by_id("post-count"))
```

Note that I included the use of `WebDriverWait(...).until(...)` to allow the elements to be created dynamically just in case.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the WebDriver to wait implicitly until the element is visible.

```
browser.implicitly_wait(30)
result = browser.find_element_by_id("post-count")
```